# encrypt / to hide a message in Latin

Tags: vocabulary, passage-request

What was the verb(s) the Romans used when the hide/encrypt a message in another text (and also the antonym "to decipher")? After consulting *Döderlein's Hand-book of Latin Synonymes* ([Celare](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/33197/pg33197-images.html#word_Celare)), it was difficult to fixate on a word.

Latin Vicipaedia ([Cryptographia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographia)) seems to suggest *obscuro* ("Cryptographi plerumque mathematicis rationibus ad nuntia obscuranda utuntur") or simply *scribo [secretum nuntium]* ("Cryptographia est ars scientiaque nuntiorum secretorum scribendorum et interpretandorum")

There surely are classical as well as medieval examples but I could not find any.

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/667/did-ancient-romans-develop-cryptography-for-latin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one relevant passage in Suetonius, *Divus Iulius*, 56.6, describing the [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher):

> Extant et ad Ciceronem, item ad familiares domesticis de rebus, in quibus, si qua occultius perferenda erant, **per notas scripsit**, id est sic structo litterarum ordine, ut nullum uerbum effici posset: quae si qui inuestigare et persequi uelit, quartam elementorum litteram, id est D pro A et perinde reliquas commutet.

> There are extant likewise some letters from him to Cicero, and others to his friends, concerning his domestic affairs; in which, if there was occasion for secrecy, **he wrote in cyphers**; that is, he used the alphabet in such a manner, that not a single word could be made out. The way to decipher those epistles was to substitute the fourth for the first letter, as D for A, and so for the other letters respectively.
> (translation by Alexander Thomson, 1889)

See [Perseus](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0061:life=jul.:chapter=56) for more context.

The bit I highlighted gives one answer to your question: *per notas scribere*.

Comment: Nice. It also suggests *investigare* to decipher

Comment: I'm guessing that "rot-III" wasn't in common usage.

Comment: Worth noting (haha) that Suetonius uses the same expression describing Augustus' even simpler cipher ([*Div. Aug.* 88](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/suetonius/suet.aug.html#88)).