# latin translation for "encrypted message"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How did Caesar say "encrypted message"?

Looking at the latin translations for kruptós increases the number of options: *hidden, concealed, private, secret*. But that's as far as I can go in finding an answer.
How would Caesar say it?

How about "cipher"?

Comment: I closed your question as a duplicate of [this](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/21392/79). If you feel it doesn't satisfy you, please edit your question in relation to the older one. I know the questions are not identical, but they are very closely related.